# Security issues with reading a JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a website that will have a JS multi-dimensional array in a .js file in the scripts folder on the server. In the array will be video embed codes (Vimeo iframes) and additional strings for composers, players and piece names. There will about 1000 videos in the array.

```
var videos = [ ['embed code', 'composer name', 'player name', 'piece name'], ['embed code', 'composer name', 'player name', 'piece name']...];
```

There will be a search text box for users to do specific searches by composer, player, etc. A jQuery script will iterate through each inner array to find matches to the user's query and present them on the page. It will look basically like this:

```
function getArray(video) {
     if (campyear === video[j]) {
       var pos = video.indexOf(video[j]);                  
        $('#searcharea').append('<td>' + video[(pos - pos)] + '</td><td><h3>Composer: ' + video[(pos -pos) + 1] + '</h3><br><h3>Player: ' + video[(pos - pos) + 2] + '</h3><br><h3>Piece: ' + video[(pos - pos) + 3] + '</h3></td>');
     } 
      else 
        noResultCount++;                    

      if (campyear === video[j] && count % 2 === 0)
        $('#searcharea').append('</tr><tr>');

      if (campyear === video[j])
        count++;

      if (i === videos.lenght && j === 4)
        $('#searcharea').append('</table>');

      if (noResultCount === videos.length * 5) 
        $('#searcharea').html("<h4>No results found for " + yearvalue + " " + buttonvalue + ". Not all camps have videos for every year.</h4>");
        $('#searcharea').fadeIn(500);

    } // End of getArray()
...
...
...

for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        getArray(videos[i]);           
        }
      }
```

I know there are security issues with the traditional SQL databases and PHP that need to be considered, but in this case should I be concerned about any threats to the data or website? My thought was the script can only read the data and print it so there wasn't much someone could do, but I'm not sure. The data isn't sensitive.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: All javascript source is public, but if your data is not sensitive it should not pose a problem

Comment: The array contains data you want people to "see", right? If so, why should there be a security problem?

Comment: "a JS multi-dimensional array in a .js file " -- stop right there. If you're not using [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for this, you should be.

Comment: @Blazemonger You're right. I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is that if someone can alter the file before it gets read in, they can inject any JavaScript code into it.** One way to alter the file would be to hack your server, but they could also do it by taking over proxies that don't have to touch your machine at all. They they would have to somehow trick clients into going through the proxy, but you can't stop that from happening.

**The easiest fix for this is to use a JSON file instead of a JavaScript file.** JSON's syntax is very close to the syntax used for JS literals: as far as I can see from your example, the only changes you'd need to make to the file are to get rid of the "var videos =" at the start and swap your single-quotes for double-quotes. In code, exchange whatever works to this effect:

```
// Assume that getJS() grabs your JavaScript file
// and returns a String with the text of that file.
var videoCode = getJS();
eval(videoCode);
```

...for something that works like this:

```
// Assume that getJSONData() grabs your JSON
// and returns a String with the text of the file.
jsonData = getJSONData();
var videos = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

**Note that we're using `JSON.parse` (which has polyfills for old browsers) instead of `eval`**. We do this because that puts the code through a dedicated JSON parser instead of a JavaScript one. JSON doesn't know how to deal with code, so even if an attacker tries to inject code by changing the file, the changed code won't work, because JSON won't know what to do with it. Obviously you don't want your app to just stop in the middle, but it's better than letting the attacker take over.

Comment: If someone could modify the JS file that contains the data, they could probably also modify the JS file that contains the actual application logic. By that logic, I should not write a website at all, because everything could be hijacked.

Comment: @FelixKling: That only holds if your data always comes from static files, which isn't a very safe assumption to make. More and more applications are getting dynamically-generated JSON, including JSON generated from user content.This last case opens you up, in theory, to XSS issues on the server side: a user can try to create malformed input that tricks your app into injecting arbitrary JavaScript into the data it sends, all without touching any files on the server. Using a proper JSON parser guards against that possibility: even if an XSS bug shows up, the JSON parser won't let it through.